# Are there any downsides to hiding sub navigation in a menu using css position absolute offset?

Tags: html, css, menu, accessibility

Using the offset technique to hide a nested navigation menu, i.e. giving

```
position : absolute
left : -9999em
```

to the sub menus and then on hover, change it to `left:0;`

Code - https://codepen.io/yogesharora28/pen/WNNPQKV

Could there be any potential issues using this way? One thing I noticed is that, using screen readers for accessibility, if you use short cut keys in screen reader, all the links in the sub menu will be coming up in that and you will have to tab through all links in sub menu.

Not sure, if this is desired or not.

Comment: Note that asking for opinions "is ... a good technique?" "is it okay to...", etc. is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to focus on the objective matter of downsides.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @HereticMonkey. I will keep that in mind going ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People using technology assistance are not always fully blind.

1. Imagine being read some text on the screen and not being able to view it simultaneously and not being able to click it.
2. The fact that it's never hidden for screenreaders also is problematic, People using screenreaders will be forced to be read each element of the different submenus while it might be unnecessary. People may object that they still can use some shortcut to go to the next element, but not all screenreader users are comfortable with shortcuts. 
   Consider that people with disabilities must have the same experience than everybody. If you consider that you have to hide submenus (to make navigation easier), then you should do it for everyone.

Using `display:none` is a better option.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. This clarifies a lot. I was initially using display:none only, but was facing a weird problem with NVDA screen reader, but when used the offset property like left:-9999em instead of display:none, that fixed the problem. Would you be able to help on that too, have described that problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929504/nvda-not-reading-text-in-navigation-using-arrow-keys

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, tabbing could get tedious...  particularly for keyboard users when the sub menus are long. As an alternate approach, I'd suggest you read up on the ARIA `menubar` role... which pretty much does what you want but in a standardized way:

Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#menubar

Working examples: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html

Comment: hey @TimHayes, as what i understand, we should not be using aria roles for pure navigation menus on a website. Hence didnt use this. My understanding comes from a few article's i read, one of them being - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/building-accessible-menu-systems/

Comment: @whyAto8 - that looks like an interesting article that I'll read more in depth when I have the time. But that second link I posted from the WAI-ARIA group provides an example for doing exactly what you want... creating an ARIA a menubar for site navigation menus. If it wasn't a good idea, it wouldn't be featured as a best practice by the group that maintains the spec. And their example does not have "menuitem elements with interactive descendants." Their menuitem elements are the anchor tags themselves, which should be legal as far as I understand.

Comment: Again, from what i have read and from my exp, roles such as menubar and menu are mostly used for when you have a desktop like menu OR are building a widget. But when you have a simple navigation menu, you should not be using that. The first article https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#menubar also says so, if you search for desktop word, you will find that easily. Also, please see this thread - https://adrianroselli.com/2017/10/dont-use-aria-menu-roles-for-site-nav.html

Comment: Fair enough. I suggest you take a look at this alternative ARIA example: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html. It uses a similar interface, but without the ARIA menubar role. The keyboard support is pretty intuitive.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be more apt. Thanks for the link.